# abort: could not find web.cacerts: C:\Program Files (x86)\Mercurial\cacert.pem

Tags: mercurial, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

I'm new to Mercurial. I created a Bitbucket account, created a new private repo, and then tried to clone using the repo. I got this error: abort: could not find web.cacerts: C:\Program Files (x86)\Mercurial\cacert.pem

I'm not sure how to handle this as Google has given me a number of different solutions that seem to vary depending on the specifics of the case, and I would prefer not to screw anything up by changing a config file incorrectly. Note that I'm using embedded Mercurial in Sourcetree. Any ideas or help?

Answer (score 20):

Open `C:\Users\[UserName]\AppData\Local\Atlassian\SourceTree\hg_local\Mercurial.ini`

And change:

`cacerts=C:\Program Files (x86)\Mercurial\cacert.pem`

with:

`cacerts=C:\Users\[UserName]\AppData\Local\Atlassian\SourceTree\hg_local\cacert.pem`